# Calculating remaining days in a month

Tags: php

So suppose I have a user that is capable of choosing a certain date in the month. If he would, let's say, choose the 16th of October 2014, I want to display the remaining days of the month as a calendar.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$data  = $_POST['input'];
$days = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');

$m = date('m'); $y = date('y');
$d = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$m,$y);

for ($i=1;$i<;$i++){ 
    echo $i + 1; 
}
```

Code is pretty messy as of now. I just have no way to go round this, that is why I asked.

Comment: you want to get remaining number of days ?

Comment: remaining number of days = number of days in month - selected day

Comment: Not number. I just want to list them as they are. i.e. 16th is Thursday. I need to output Friday (17th), Saturday (18th), Sunday (19th), Monday (20th) etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://www.php.net/date).

For the format of `date` you can use the following:

> **`'t'`** Number of days in the given month (*28 through 31*)
>   **`'j'`** Day of the month without leading zeros (*1 to 31*)

```
<?php

$timestamp = strtotime('2014-10-03');

$daysRemaining = (int)date('t', $timestamp) - (int)date('j', $timestamp);

var_dump($daysRemaining); // int(28)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/201389)

---

**Edit**: Apparently you want to list the remaining days in the month:

```
<?php

$timestamp = strtotime('2014-10-03');
$yearMonth = date('Y-m-', $timestamp);

$daysInMonth = (int)date('t', $timestamp);

for ($i = (int)date('j', $timestamp); $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++) {
    $dateString = date('l \t\h\e jS \o\f F', strtotime($yearMonth . $i));

    var_dump($dateString);
}

/*
    string(25) "Friday the 3rd of October"
    string(27) "Saturday the 4th of October"
    string(25) "Sunday the 5th of October"
    string(25) "Monday the 6th of October"
    string(26) "Tuesday the 7th of October"
    string(28) "Wednesday the 8th of October"
    string(27) "Thursday the 9th of October"
    string(26) "Friday the 10th of October"
    string(28) "Saturday the 11th of October"
    string(26) "Sunday the 12th of October"
    string(26) "Monday the 13th of October"
    string(27) "Tuesday the 14th of October"
    string(29) "Wednesday the 15th of October"
    string(28) "Thursday the 16th of October"
    string(26) "Friday the 17th of October"
    string(28) "Saturday the 18th of October"
    string(26) "Sunday the 19th of October"
    string(26) "Monday the 20th of October"
    string(27) "Tuesday the 21st of October"
    string(29) "Wednesday the 22nd of October"
    string(28) "Thursday the 23rd of October"
    string(26) "Friday the 24th of October"
    string(28) "Saturday the 25th of October"
    string(26) "Sunday the 26th of October"
    string(26) "Monday the 27th of October"
    string(27) "Tuesday the 28th of October"
    string(29) "Wednesday the 29th of October"
    string(28) "Thursday the 30th of October"
    string(28) "Friday the 31st of October"
*/
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/201409)

Comment: Is `$timestamp` unused intentionally?

Comment: But that's about the count of days remaining. How can I list those days?

Comment: I did. Thank you :) I added a bit of style and am now trying to place a breakline once every seven iterations.

Answer (score 7):

Why you complicate it so much use date('t') to get number of days in month you can do for example:

```
echo date('t') - date('j');
```

which will count remaining days in current month.

If you want to get remaining days from particular date use

```
$date = strtotime($_POST['input']);
echo date('t', $date) - date('j', $date);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = new DateTime();

$lastDayOfThisMonth = new DateTime('last day of this month');

$nbOfDaysRemainingThisMonth =  $lastDayOfThisMonth->diff($today)->format('%a days');

echo "Remaining Days Of This Month = ";
echo $nbOfDaysRemainingThisMonth;
```