# Reset countdown every new month

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a countdown reset every first day of month (for example 01.02.2019). It's a monthly billing, but I want it to show "x days until next bill".

I've set up a simple code, but I'm new to PHP so I'd like to know how to reset it every 1th.

```
<?php

$mysqldate = $_SESSION['u_time'];
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
$mysqldate = date( 'd.m.Y', $phpdate );


$oysterContract = date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+3 month", $phpdate));
$dinnerContract = date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+6 month", $phpdate));
$mediumContract = date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+10 month", $phpdate));
$myContract = date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+3 month", $phpdate));

$date = strtotime($myContract);
$remaining = $date - time();

$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600 );


?>
```

Right now, when you sign up it will go from 30 to 0, but after 0 it goes -1, -2 etc.. I'd like it to reset! Anyone?

Comment: I'm not sure but, can't you make an if statement if 0 just reset it?

Comment: What is even involved in a "reset"? Looks like you pull a date out of a database to decide when the next payment is due?

Comment: @JonStirling the date is when the user registred.

Comment: I think this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26175845) should help you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't help. But thanks

Comment: That's pretty normal. Registration date (understood as the day when the user first registered to the system) of the user is static. So even if you put +3 month on it you will some day be 'in the past' ==> negative 'remaining' value.
May be you are looking for the 'last logged in date' (understood as the date of the current active logged in session or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo (new DateTime('first day of next month'))->diff(new DateTime())->format('%a days');
```